# Codeigniter pass data to same model function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is the basic structure what I'm wanna to do. Advance thanks for suggestion.

```
public function a()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('a');
    return $query;
}

public function update(){
    //how to pass data here from function a
     //like $query->id
     //$query->name 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function a()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('a');
    $this->update($query); 
}

public function update($query)
{
    $id = $query->row()->id; //depends on $query contents 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. How to extract data from $query here.

Comment: Accept as answer please.